# Получение доступа к компьютеру с windows server 2008 r2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

На сервере был установлен контроллер домена. Появилась необходимость удалить контроллер. После удаления не могу подключиться к серверу. Ввожу учетные данные локального администратора. Но на сервер попасть не могу. Что делать, подскажите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вышел из положения: Загрузился с обычного LiveCD, который поддерживает имеющийся RAID, и создал нового администратора при помощи соответствующей программы.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже Вы знаете данные только доменного администратора, который не является локальным пользователем. Проще всего будет загрузиться с диска/флэшки во что-то наподобие Hiren'S boot CD и сбросить пароль локального администратора.

Comment: Дело в том, что на сервере установлен RAID, а программы, которые я пробовал для решения этой проблемы, с ним работать не могут

Comment: есть шанс, что свежая убунта поддерживает аппаратный **неизвестный** пока что рэйд. Дальше "ubuntu reset windows password"

Comment: @klutch1991 Придётся делать свой WinPE с интегрированным драйвером RAID-контроллера.

Comment: @АлексейПрисяжный Подозреваю, что RAID там псевдо-аппаратный.

Comment: А можно как-то добавить драйвер в уже имеющийся образ диска для сброса паролей?

Comment: у меня есть iso-образ

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613857.aspx - собственно результат по запросу "win pe iso drivers add"